# How come Gdiplus SolidBrush's RGB is different from regular RGB?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to paint a simple header on top of my Window with Gdiplus' SolidBrush, but whenever I set the RGB color it's different from what it's suppose to be.

How come this is happening? And is there a way to fix that?
Thanks!

**Gdiplus' SolidBrush RGB:**

[image]

**Regular RGB:**

[image]

Comment: Format is ARGB. So just use 255, 255, 255, 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [`Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdipluscolor/nf-gdipluscolor-color-color(byte_byte_byte_byte)) constructor taking four arguments, `a`, `r`, `g`, and `b`, in this order. `(255, 255, 0, 0)` thus means: Fully opaque (first value), red channel at full intensity (second value), and no contribution from other color channels.

In other words: You're creating a fully opaque red brush as illustrated in the application screenshot.

If you wish to create a `Color` value from the color channels only, there's a convenience [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdipluscolor/nf-gdipluscolor-color-color(byte_byte_byte)) taking `r`, `g`, and `b` arguments. The opacity is implied to be 255 (i.e. fully opaque).

```cpp
Gdiplus::SolidBrush brush(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0));
```

creates a fully opaque, bright yellow brush.